# where to use parallel hint in oracle

Tags: oracle, parallel-processing, oracle12c, with-statement, hints

I have a technical question about parallel hint.

let's suppose I have complex statement with several WITH clauses or maybe some subquery.
where shoud I place the hint if it is on statement level or table level

with a1 as (
select ....
),
a2 as (
select ....
)
select * from a1 join a2 on ......
where no exists ( select '1' from another_table)

all WITH clauses and another_table produce many rows so at statement level is oracle smart enough and the hint /*+parallel 16*/ will do just once in the first WITH cluse a1 or does it make sense to place similar hint in every WITH clause and subquery as well.
what is the best practice in such scenarios?

thanks